# modular arithmetic questions concerning the sum of reciprocals

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

I'm trying to prove the sum of reciprocals from 1 to (p-1) is divisible by p^2.

Someone showed me how to prove it. But there's a step which I don't grasp. (Or maybe I misunderstood.)

He changed the form of the sum from 1+1/2+...+1/(p-1) to p{1/(p-1)+1/2(p-2)+...+1/{(p-1)/2×(p+1)/2} and first considering only the sum of 1/(p-k)k where k is from 1 to (p-1)/2.

He said in the numerator of the sum of 1/(p-k)k , will appear every term of (p-k)k from 1 to (p-1)/2.

But I cannot show how to gurantee it.

Could you give me any hints or advice?

Comment: If $p=3$ then you are looking at $\frac 11 + \frac 12=\frac 32$, yes?  In what sense is $\frac 32$ divisible by $3^2=9$?

Comment: @lulu I forgot to say p is odd prime greater or equal to 5.

Comment: And that you are only interested in the numerator?

Comment: @lulu I've already searched that column. But I want to make the "hole" filled.